# Many-to-many² relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, database-design

I'm in a situation I haven't see before. 
I'm working in a system that has integrations with other sensorial systems. Basically, a machine has several sensors and these sensors generate inputs into the system. Each input has its ID in my database and a "measurement" ID that may repeat for a period. In my system, the user can then relate the "measurement ID" with a "machine ID" in order to tell that a measurement is for a machine. Here is how it looks:

[image: database diagram]

And notice how the following scenario is a valid one:

[image: data example]

Notice how one `Measuremente ID` on the M x N table referes to more than one record on the `Sensor Measurements` table (that's why I'm calling this M x N²).

I know that this is not the perfect database modelling but unfortunelly this is a legacy database that **I can't change**.

That being said, how can I model this in JPA? Basically I would like to have a `Set` of `SensorMeasurements` in my `Machine` entity. I'm about to try but I'm guessing a `@ManyToMany` won't work here.

Any ideas or tips is really welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why should it not work that way? I would guess that it should work just fine as you still have a list of  `SensorMeasurements` for one `Machine`

Comment: I may have get ahead of myself posting before trying but I guess `@ManyToMany` only works if it references unique objects on the other tables. Am I wrong assuming this?

Comment: I havent tried that specific setup so far, but to me it still looks like a viable `ManyToMany`. And I would assume that you are wrong suumin it this way. because you can have duplicates `Measurements` which only differ by `ID` thus are not really unique

Comment: It's not clear, but is `Measuremente ID` on the middle table is the PK? If so, I can't really see how many-to-many would work. It looks like the relationships are machines have many sensors that have many measurements. In the Machine entity you could map the middle table as a Set, and in the entity for the middle table map the measurements as another Set.

Comment: Indeed the `@ManyToMany` does not work because there is no relationship between `Sensor Measurements` and `Measurement x Machine`. It neither could exist because the `Measurement ID` can repeat on the `Sensor Measurements` table. Is it possible to use JPA annotations in this case (when there is no relationship)? Any ideas?

Comment: If the data has consistency, then it should work, even if there is not an actual FK  constraint. If you can do the join in SQL, the JPA mapping should work.

Comment: @VitorSantos you were right. I did not know that. Also, your solution of having 2 OneToMany relationship is the one that worked for me. Valeu!